# Sitecore: Access Context from an asmx webservice

Tags: web-services, asmx, sitecore

As stated in the subject. I am trying to access my Sitecore context from an independent .asmx web service. Was wondering whether or not theres a proper way of doing it.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sitecore Context should be available in a classic ASMX web service, however, because a request to the service may not provoke the default Sitecore pipelines, it is a good idea to set the site context as follows:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string MyServiceMethod()
{
    using (new SiteContextSwitcher(SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext("website")))
    {
        // Here you can access Sitecore.Context
    }
}
```

Comment: This should only be necessary if the ASMX service is added to IgnoreUrls.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore is fairly greedy about handling all URL requests that hit the application. The easy way around this is to a[dd the URL to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/using-ajax-scriptmanager-under-sitecore/). However, this denies you access to some Sitecore Context values, such as Site and Database, which Sitecore could still resolve based on the host name.

I'd recommending adding a processor to the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline which aborts the pipeline at the right moment (right before `ExecuteRequest`) if the URL appears to be your asmx service. An example of doing this for MVC requests can be found [here](https://github.com/leethomascook/SitecoreMVC/blob/master/Aqueduct.MVC.Sitecore/SystemWebRoutingResolver.cs). For your asmx service, you'll probably need to check the URL string directly. Bonus points for configuring that URL using a property on the processor class (c.f. [Sitecore Configuration Factory](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/02/The-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS-Configuration-Factory.aspx)).